# SQL to group and sum subitem and parent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issues trying to figure out how to group and sum subitem with parent item rows.

I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
select 
  topics.name,
  sum(commission_amount) as commission
from orders
left join topics
on topics.id = orders.topic_id
group by 1
```

This works, however I'm trying to group and use only parent topic names.

Topics table:

| id | name | topic_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Meal Delivery | NULL |
| 2 | Vegan Meal Delivery | 1 |
| 3 | Vegetarian Meal Delivery | 1 |
| 4 | Mattresses | NULL |
| 5 | Hybrid Mattress | 4 |
| 6 | Memory Foam Mattress | 4 |

So a parent topic is when topic_id = NULL

Orders table:

| id | topic_id | commission_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 4 | 40 |
| 5 | 5 | 50 |
| 6 | 6 | 60 |

Desired output is this:

| name | commission |
| --- | --- |
| Meal Delivery | 60 |
| Mattresses | 150 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler look of the answer using self-join.

```
SELECT t1.name, SUM(o.commision_amount) AS commision
FROM topics t1
INNER JOIN topics t2 ON t1.id = t2.topic_id OR t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN orders o ON t2.id = o.topic_id
WHERE t1.topic_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c84e8fd83d8bd0f4d49435967a9c2e6)

Answer (score 1):

Join with `topics` again.

```
SELECT name, SUM(commission) AS commission
FROM (
    -- subtopic commissions
    SELECT t1.name, IFNULL(SUM(o.commission_amount), 0) AS commission
    FROM topics AS t1
    LEFT JOIN topics AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.topic_id
    LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.topic_id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.topic_id IS NULL -- only show parent topics
    GROUP BY t1.name
    
    UNION ALL
    -- parent topic commissions
    SELECT t.name, IFNULL(SUM(o.commission_amount), 0) AS commission
    FROM topics AS t
    LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.topic_id = t.id
    WHERE t.topic_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.name
) AS x
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks @barmar. One issue with your query is it doesn't include the parent topic commission values in the total. Here's what I get when I test your query:

`Meal Delivery: 50 & Mattresses: 110`

Comment: I've updated the answer to union with a query that gets the parent topic commissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self-join to bring all parent topics, and children to the same level:

```
select TPnt.Name, sum(O.Commission_amount) as Commission_amount
from 
     Topics TPnt

     inner join
     Topics TChld
     on TPnt.Id=coalesce(TChld.topic_id, TChld.id)

     inner join
     Orders O
     on O.topic_id=TChld.id

group by TPnt.Name
```